# The tags [hashing] and [checksum]: do we need both?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been considering writing a couple of checksum-based challenges, and while checking for duplicates, I noticed that both [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing) and [checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checksum) exist.

Now, hashing and checksums aren't the same thing, but people seem to be using them fairly interchangeably, and they're certainly related in spirit. There are three solutions I can think of (and maybe other solutions that people will think of in the answers):

1. Ensure that the tags have no overlap, going through all questions that use either and making sure the tag is appropriate;
2. Make the tags into synonyms, and use them interchangeably from then on;
3. Make one of the tags into a subset of the other (so all challenges about checksums or hashing will have one of the tags in particular, and a subset will have both).

Which of these options will lead to the best categorisations of these sorts of questions?

Comment: I apologise for the awkward wording of the title; SE doesn't let you start a question with a square bracket.

Comment: I'm guessing somebody has been doing some cleanup:  I only see two questions tagged [tag:checksum], and neither of them are tagged [tag:hashing]

Comment: But isn't comparing hashing and checksums like comparing apples and oranges. Actually, more like fruit and apples not that I think about it..

Comment: He mentioned that: "Now, hashing and checksums aren't the same thing, but people seem to be using them fairly interchangeably, and they're certainly related in spirit"

Comment: Full disclosure: I updated the tag wiki (actually, created: it didn't previously have one) for [tag:hashing] to match how the tag's being used in practice, and thus explicitly listing checksum problems as a valid use for the tag. If people disagree with that, it may need to be re-edited.

Answer (score 4):

## Make [checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checksum) a synonym for [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing)

Although hashing and checksums aren't the same thing, a checksum can certainly be seen as a sort of simple hashing algorithm. As such, [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing) isn't *inappropriate* for a checksum-based problem, even though it's vaguer than it could be. (If this solution is adopted, I'd change its tag wiki to clarify that it covers both cryptographic and non-cryptographic hash functions.) The [checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checksum) tag is only sparsely used right now, and I'm not sure we would have a huge advantage to the uses of hashes in cryptography from the uses in checking for corruption (not to mention that there's a third common use of hashes on PPCG which doesn't fall nearly into either category, [classfication](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classfication), but this tends to be a property of the answers rather than the questions).

As such, the best technical solution is probably to set up a tag synonym (i.e. a redirect) from [checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checksum) to [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing); that way, anyone who tried to use [checksum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checksum) on a challenge or in the search box would get [hashing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashing) instead. If this answer is well-received, I'll officially propose the synonym.